# Standard way to add custom react-scripts in create-react-app

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, react-scripts, custom-react-scripts

I have a project created from create-react-app and is in typescript, I want to add suport for custom react-scripts without eject so what would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Khizer.

Use this package for custom scripts in TS by using this command

`create-react-app my-app --scripts-version custom-react-scripts`

[custom react script for TS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-react-scripts-ts)

BTW, which custom script you want to add

Comment: I need to add post-css support and the typescript scripts.

Comment: yes, you can use this script for css or less or scss files